# GFS model and clouds

Tags: weather, gfs

I have the task of producing a cloudiness forecasts from GFS model. I found a way to get GFS data and manipulate it with metpy, but there are multiple data about clouds, for example:
Pressure_convective_cloud_bottom
Total_cloud_cover_convective_cloud
Pressure_high_cloud_bottom_6_Hour_Average
etc

How can I produce a meaningful forecast from them? Any tips to point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

GFS output includes a value for the total cloud cover over the depth of the entire atmosphere. When accessing this data from a THREDDS server, it's called `Total_cloud_cover_entire_atmosphere`.

Comment: Thank you. I do get some data. Any hints on where to start processing it? Like reading % at each layer at each lat-lon?

Comment: This is where I'd rely on Python and numpy/xarray to calculate perhaps the maximum along the vertical axis. Other than that, though, that's really a scientific application question and would depend (to me) on how those original values are calculated.